# Cannot center 2 overlaying images

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

[image]

I've got 2 identical sized images displaying correctly with a semi-transparent 'logo' one sat on top of a base green image, but they are on the left and I need them both to be centered on the screen - I just can't figure out what I'm missing here?

```
<div class="portrait-image-wrapper">
    <img src="../image.jpg" class="base-photo"/>
    <img src="../logo.png" class="logo"/>
</div>
```

And the css

```
html,body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;}

.portrait-image-wrapper {
position: relative;
background-size: contain; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center; 
width: 467px; 
height: 700px;}

.base-photo {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: absolute; 
Z-index: 1;}

.logo {
position: absolute; 
top: 0px; 
left: 0px;
z-index: 2;}
```

I tried adding these to the portrait-image-wrapper but no effect...

```
display: flex; 
align-items: center;
```

Comment: Idon't understand the background settings - do you want the images as backgrounds rather than as separate img elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to center the .portrait-image-wrapper inside the body. So you need to add this to your css:

```
html,body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```